# Array Elements left rotation in C# - undesirable output

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, visual-studio

I am trying to create a C# function to left rotate array elements and store it in another array.

> inputl = array to which rotated array has to be stored,
>
> inputr = array to be rotated
>
> shift = number of shifts.

Even though I pass the value of shift as any value the rotation takes place only once. Please help.

```
public static void LeftShift(int[] inputl,int[] inputr, int shift)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < shift; j++)
    {
            int temp = inputr[0];
            var last = inputr.Length - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < last; i++)
            {
                inputl[i] = inputr[i+1];
            }
            inputl[last] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: You shift the same array (*inputr*) n times, you get the same output beacuse *inputr* doesn't change. You have to use the new array (*inputl*) as source array in the next iteration./

Comment: Or do `var inputr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    int shift = 2;
    var inputl = inputr.Skip(shift).Concat( inputr.Take(shift) ).ToArray();` just for fun.

Comment: I love this (above) solution, illustrates the power of C# + Linq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution to your problem:

```
public static void shift(int[]al, int[]ar,int shift)
{
   shift=ar.Length-shift%ar.Length;
   for (int i = 0; i < ar.Length; i++)
       al[(i+shift)%al.Length]=ar[i];
}
```

If you remove the first line inside the shift method the output will be a right shift

Answer (score 0):

Hope I could understand your problem and this is what you want

```
public static void shift(int[]al, int[]ar,int shift)
{
    int ind=0;
    for (int i = shift; i < ar.Length; i++)
    {
        al[ind] = ar[i];
        ind++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < shift; i++)
    {
        al[ind] = ar[i];
        ind++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved above program using below code.

```
public static List<int> rotateLeft(int d, List<int> arr) {
    int n = arr.Count;
    List<int> t = new List<int>();
    int h = d;

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    { 
        if ((j + d) % n == 0)
        {
            h = 0;
        }
       
        t.Add(arr[h]);
        h++;
    } 

    return t;
}
```